# Remove Theme Options Button from Wordpress Admin Bar

Tags: php, wordpress, wp-admin

[image: Theme Options]

How to remove the "Theme Options" button from the Wordpress Admin Bar.

Note that the path of the linked page is:

wp-admin/admin.php?page=mytheme-options

I have tried both remove_menu_page and remove_submenu_page functions.

Answer (score 0):

Try to increse or decrease the action priority. See [add_action#parameters](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_action/#parameters):

> **$priority**
> (int) (Optional) Used to specify the order in which the functions associated with a particular action are executed. Lower numbers correspond with earlier execution, and functions with the same priority are executed in the order in which they were added to the action.
>
> Default value: 10